# how to if else on controller for search function?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, if-statement

So i have a controller with a basic search function and i want to know when a user click the search button if there is data exist i want it to return the same page with error message, but if data not exist i want return another page. how can i do that? my code as below:

controller:

```html
public function search(Request $request, $companyID, $entityType)
 {
  $data = [];
  $intentTypes = DiraQuestion::select('intent')->where('company_id', $companyID)->groupBy('intent')->get();

  foreach ($intentTypes as $intent) 
  {
   $data[$intent->intent] = $intent->intent;
  }

  $q = $request->q;
     $user = DiraQuestion::select('eVal')->where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->groupBy('eVal')->get();

     return view('AltHr.Chatbot.addType', compact('data','entityType','companyID'))->withDetails($user)->withQuery($q);
 }
```

my current view page which shows if exist and if not exist shows form:

```html
@if(isset($details))
<div class="container-fluid container-fixed-lg">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- <div class="panel-heading">
     <div class="panel-title"><b>{{ $query }}</b></div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div> -->
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="form-group edit-response-container">
      <div class="col-md-12">
       @foreach($details as $user)
                 <p><span style="color:red;">{{$user->eVal}}</span> is already included!</p>
                @endforeach
            </div>

      @if($details->isEmpty())
      <form action="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\ChatbotController@addQType', [$companyID, $entityType])}}" method="post">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       <!-- @if(empty($data))
       <p>No predefined intents.</p>
       @else -->
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
         <label>New Type</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="entityValue" placeholder="{{$query}}" value="{{$query}}" required readonly/>
        </div>
       </div>
       <!-- <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
         <label>New Question</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="question" placeholder="Enter Sample Question" required>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
         <label>Intent</label>
         <select class="full-width" name="intent" data-init-plugin="select2" required>
          <option selected disabled></option>
                      @foreach($data as $datas)
                      <option value="{{$datas}}">{{$datas}}</option>
                      @endforeach
         </select>
        </div>
       </div> -->
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="new-field">
         <div class="form-group-attached">
          <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
           <label>Synonyms:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="syn" placeholder="Enter Synonyms" />
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <p><i>*Enter All Synonyms Separating With ','</i></p>
       </div>


       <div class="col-md-12">
        <br>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn alt-btn-green alt-btn btn-xs add-new">Add Synonym</button> -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn alt-btn-green alt-btn btn-xs">Save</button>

        <a href="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\ChatbotController@newTest', [$companyID, $entityType])}}" class="btn alt-btn-green alt-btn btn-xs">test</a>

       </div>
       @endif
      </form>
      @endif
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
@endif
```

route:

```html
Route::post('search/{companyID}/{entityType}','Chatbot\ChatbotController@search');
```

as you can see currently if data exist, it shows error message on the same page, but if no data it shows a form on the same page itself.. i want it to route to another page when there is no data found.

Comment: is your search function is a post method??

Comment: yes it is @Sohel0415

Comment: could you please share your route definition and explain which url you want to redirect according to your conditions????

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `include` another `snippet` inside of your `@if` then you can do so like this:

```
@include('route.to.view')
```

Which will search for the `blade` view in that url and insert the html in case when there is `$data` present

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you mean

Comment: If you want to show a piece of `HTML` or another page inside of your current page, you can use `@include` instead of `redirecting` the user to that page